# Line integrals along a line

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification, parametrization, line-integrals

Compute the following integrals:

- $$\int_{\overline {AB}}^{ }\left(\cos\left(2y\right)dx-2x\sin\left(2y\right)dy\right)$$
- $$\int_{\overline {AB}}^{ }\left(\tan\left(y\right)dx+x\sec^{2}\left(y\right)dy\right)$$

Where $A=(1,\frac{\pi}{6}), B=(2,\frac{\pi}{4})$.

---

The line can be parameterized as $$C: r(t)=(t,\frac{\pi}{12}(t+1)), \;\;\; t \in [1,2]$$

So:$$\int_{\overline {AB}}^{ }\left(\cos\left(2y\right)dx-2x\sin\left(2y\right)dy\right)$$$$=\frac{6}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cos\left(t\right)+\left(-t+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\sin\left(t\right)\right)dt$$$$=\frac{6}{\pi}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}-1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{12}\right)$$$$=-1/2$$

---

$$\int_{\overline {AB}}^{ }\left(\tan\left(y\right)dx+x\sec^{2}\left(y\right)dy\right)$$$$=\int_{1}^{2}\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\left(t+1\right)\right)+t\sec^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\left(t+1\right)\right)\frac{\pi}{12}\right)dt$$$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan\left(t\right)+\left(t-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)\sec^{2}\left(t\right)\right)dt$$$$=\frac{\sqrt{12}-1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

I want to know how much of my work is correct.

Comment: You write down a parametrization where $t$ ranges from $1$ to $2$ and then give an integral where $t$ ranges from $\frac{\pi}3$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Why?

Comment: @  Christoph, I used the substitution $$\pi/6(t+1) \mapsto t$$

Comment: Both your answers are correct. But you can apply fundamental theorem of line integral to simplify your working. Let me know if you have any questions on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that both vector fields are conservative and are gradients of a scalar function.

$\vec F = \nabla f(x,y)$

So by Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral,

$\displaystyle \int_C (\nabla f) \cdot dr = f(b) - f(a), \ $ where $a$ and $b$ are start and end points respectively.

For the first one, $\vec F = \langle\cos(2y), -2x\sin(2y)\rangle = \nabla (x \cos (2y))$

Hence the line integral for the first one is $ \  2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) - \cos (\frac{\pi}{3}) = - \dfrac{1}{2}$

For the second one, note that $\vec F = \nabla (x \tan y)$ so you can again apply fundamental theorem of line integral.